# Scala: How to edit visibility of abstract method stubs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I'm trying out tight visibility controlling, and have the following kind of situation:

```
trait Foo {
  private[myPackage] def greeting()
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}
```

Now I'll have an error about greeting not being defined in the concrete class Bar, but when I auto-generate missing methods, this is the result:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  def greeting(): Unit = {
    ???
  }
}
```

I'd like to include the visibility statement into the stub as well. How to do this?